# Building flip up seat - correct hinge

Tags: wood, hinges

I'm looking to build a self-tipping seat such as what you'd find in a cinema or sports stadium. What kind of hinge system would it require? I can't seem to find anything online.

Thanks

Comment: A movie theater seat of course. Sometimes you can find used ones on Craigslist.

Comment: I think it's just a torsion spring around the axle the seat pivots on, with one end attached to the side of the frame and the other to the seat.

You might also search for lecture hall chairs - they're often of similar design.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a torsion spring, or several other types of spring depending upon your design. Or it can be done with a counter-balance.

The counter balance only requires you to set the pivot point of the hinge forward a bit with a weight on the bottom close to the back of the chair bottom. You can practice with a few designs in cardboard to see how adding a weight to a beam and placing the hinge higher or lower and forward and back until you get a feel for how it will behave.

Drew K

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2312638A/en?oq=US31288940A) shows how it is constructed and how it works, whether expired or not.  This was in the search results of trying to find the hinge or see how to make one.

[image]

[image]